# How to add existing images to R-exams questions

Tags: r, r-exams

In RMarkdown I usually use somewhat like

````
```{r}
knitr::include_graphics("myimage.png")
```
````

to add already existing images to the output, but this doesn't work via `exams2xyz()`.
`fig.path = "", fig.caption = ""` does not fix the problem.
The classic  Markdown way `![alt text](figures/img.png)`doesn't work, too.

Any ideas, where I'm wrong?

EDIT: Thank's to @jaySF I'm now aware of an working directory issue, but still face the challange to embed the figures into (e.g.) the .xml-questions for moodle import.

Comment: You probably have a mess with your working directory. Check `getwd()`. E.g. `figures/img.png` yields sth. like `C:/YOURWD/figures/img.png`. Does that help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** See the worked example in the `Rlogo.Rmd` exercises provided within the package: `exams2html("Rlogo.Rmd")` and http://www.R-exams.org/templates/Rlogo/

**Details:** The `exams` package (more specifically the `xexams()` workhorse function) do all the handling of the temporary directories. The exercises templates (`.Rmd` or `.Rnw`) are copied to a temporary directory, weaved/knitted there, read into R, and then the output file(s) are produced in some output directory. That's why some strategies from `knitr` don't work for `.Rmd` exams - or they just work in certain situations, e.g., when specifying full paths (rather than relative paths).

**Solution:** To make `exams` recognize a certain existing file (not necessarily just graphics) as a supplement to a certain exercise, the `.Rmd` file should simply copy that file to the current directory when the file is weaved/knitted. The convenience function `include_supplement()` does exactly that and additionally searches certain directories (specifically `edir`, if specified) for the files. Subsequently, the copied file `"foo.ext"` needs to be included in the exercise, e.g., via `![](foo.ext)` for a graphic or `[foo.ext](foo.ext)` for a hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks Achim - really sophisticated approach (all the more in my lay eyes)! As it works with `exams2arsnova()`, too it additionally prevents me from annoying image uploads to flickr etc. and embedding them into the questions.

Comment: Yes, exactly. By default the supplementary file/graphic is simply included in each resulting exercise via Base64 encoding. Of course, if you have large static files, it would be better to upload them else (e.g., flickr) and include only the hyperlink. But for smaller supplements the convenience and robustness of including it everywhere justifies the additional storage requirements.

Comment: It doesn't work with `exam2moodle()` though. If I include an image in Rmd with ![](<the path to the image>/image.png) The image is displayed in moodle with a generic placeholder and the link to the image is <base-moodle-link>/<the path to the image>/image.png. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't specify the full path to image in the markdown code. Instead use `![](image.png)` and use `include_supplement("<the path to the image>/image.png")` in an R chunk in the exercise. The full path can even be omitted if it is the same as the directory of the exercise. _[Note: This is actually what my answer above tries to point out. Maybe this is clearer if you re-read it now?]_